# Is the solar system the only survivor of cosmic evolution?

Tags: solar-system, observable-universe, solar-system-evolution, outer-solar-system, galactic-evolution

A question has entered my mind, we know that all the phenomena in the universe are several thousand light years away from us, so the light we see from them is related to the past few years, now my question is whether this possibility exists Is it that we are alone in the universe and all of them have been destroyed and only the solar system and we are left from the evolution of the universe?

Comment: By definition, we get no information the unobservable universe. But just because we can't know doesn't mean that we should write "here be monsters" on the map. So this can't be answered with facts, but you might look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum_decay

Comment: *we know that all the phenomena in the universe are several thousand light years away from us* No. The closest star that's visible (to the naked eye), Alpha Centauri, is just under 4.4 light-years from us, and most visible stars are within a few hundred light-years. See  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/10260/16685

Answer (score 3):

Leaving aside the incorrect notion that "all the phenomena are several thousand light years away", why would that happen?

The universe appears to follow rules - the laws of physics. They are what allow us to function and make plans on the basis that we do know, for example, that the Earth will continue to revolve and the Sun will rise tomorrow.

If you want abandon these rules (and rationality) then of course anything could happen and anything is possible.